# GCC's __builtin_expect assembly dump seems to always go down branch

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly

Ok so I have been playing around with __builtin_expect a bit and I just created a simple test program that I put through godbolt.org to get the assembly output (https://godbolt.org/g/FZo5fP)

```
int main(){
  volatile int num = 4;
  //if(num == 4){
  if(__builtin_expect(num,4)){
    return num*800;
  }else{
    return num*500;
  }
}
```

When compiled with -O1 or greater produces:

```
main:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        test    eax, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        je      .L2
        imul    eax, eax, 800
        ret
.L2:
        imul    eax, eax, 500
        ret
```

It seems as though the part that says `test eax,eax` would always set zero flag to 0 unless `num` was equal to 0. So it seems as though if `num` is not set to 0 it will always multiply by 800 instead of only when `num=4`. My understanding of __builtin_expect is that while it will  optimize to assume that it will go to that branch it should still be comparing to ensure that it should use that branch.

If I switch __builtin_expect to just == it produces

```
main:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        cmp     eax, 4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        je      .L5
        imul    eax, eax, 500
        ret
.L5:
        imul    eax, eax, 800
        ret
```

Which makes much more sense to me in that it actually compares against 4. Is my understanding of __builtin_expect wrong? Does __builtin_expect actually only work with 0 or 1 even though it specifies that it takes a long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fexpect-2284):

> The return value is the value of *exp*, which should be an integral expression.

So the logical semantics of:

```
if(__builtin_expect(num,4)) { ... }
```

are:

```
if (num) { ... }
```

which is different than what you say you want. If you want to write that you expect that `num == 4` to be very likely, you want:

```
if (__builtin_expect(num == 4, 1)) { ... }
```

Commonly, you'd just wrap these in macros:

```
#define likely(expr)   __builtin_expect((expr), 1)
#define unlikely(expr) __builtin_expect((expr), 0)
```

and then the usage becomes more natural:

```
if (likely(num == 4)) { ... }
```

Comment: So the documentation saying that the second part of it should be a long is just legacy from when bool's weren't first class citizens? Cause then it wouldn't make sense for the second arg to be anything other than 1 or 0 no?

Comment: @legion Note that this is also a C builtin. But yeah, it doesn't make much sense to pass a value other than 0 or 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the macros are supposed to be `#define likely(expr)   __builtin_expect(!!(expr), 1)` and `#define unlikely(expr) __builtin_expect(!!(expr), 0)`, which allows the idiomatic was of writing `if (likely(expr))` even if `expr` is not exclusively zero or one.

Comment: @Barry: At least not in an if statement. In a switch, on the other hand, other values may be useful.

Comment: @EOF Is `(bool)` better than `!!`?

Comment: @johnchen902: `!!` is shorter. The compiler should consider them same in terms of final machine code produced.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The problem is that `__builtin_expect()` returns an `int`, not whatever type the expression had. It's a terrible design choice that makes it far less useful than it could be. For example, if it returned the original type, you could tell the compiler how many iterations you expect a loop to run, which could be useful to make choices about unrolling/vectorizing. But if you do the sane thing and use `size_t` for your iterator, you get `signed/unsigned` ickyness.

Comment: @EOF: According to [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), the return type is `long`. And indeed it's not meant for the kind of thing you'd like to do. (And in general you should be doing FDO, not annotating source code.)